# OrientDB : Single shot Query

Tags: orientdb

I have some doubts related to the queries in orientdb. I have below scenario:

Example :

```
   Performs    Uses          RunsOn    IsConnected
```

User  -->  Process  -->  Application -->   Server -->  Network

Here, User/Process/Application/Server/Network  are Vertex Names
       Performs/Uses/RunsOn/IsConnected are Edge Names / Relationship Names
       osType/applicationName are Attribute Names for related Vertex

Now, I want all the related combination result as per the input. If input is like osType of Server and applicationName of Application then i want all the details related to this two inputs like user and process and whatever is related to this applicationName and osType.

It is possible in orientdb to fetch out all this details in a single query ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want single columns

```
 MATCH
  {as:user} -Performs-> {as:process} -Uses->
  {class:Application, as:app, where:(applicationName = ?)} -RunsOn->
  {class:Server, as:server, where:(osType = ?)} -IsConnected-> {as:network}
 RETURN user.name, process.id, app.name, server.url, server.name, network.name
```

if you only need the RIDs of the involved elements:

```
 MATCH
   {as:user} -Performs-> {as:process} -Uses->
   {class:Application, as:app, where:(applicationName = ?)} -RunsOn-> 
   {class:Server, as:server, where:(osType = ?)} -IsConnected-> {as:network}
 RETURN user, process, app, server, network
```

If you also want all the details in line:

```
 SELECT user.* as user_, process.* as process_, app.* as app_, server.* as server_, network.* as network_ FROM (
   MATCH
     {as:user} -Performs-> {as:process} -Uses->
     {class:Application, as:app, where:(applicationName = ?)} -RunsOn->      
     {class:Server, as:server, where:(osType = ?)} -IsConnected-> {as:network}
   RETURN user, process, app, server, network
 )
```

The "as xxx_" will add a prefix to attributes, this is useful to avoid collisions, eg. if you have user.name and server.name, this way you will have "user_name" and "server_name"

If you don't need all the patterns, but you only need single records that are part of the result:

```
 MATCH
   {as:user} -Performs-> {as:process} -Uses->
   {class:Application, as:app, where:(applicationName = ?)} -RunsOn-> 
   {class:Server, as:server, where:(osType = ?)} -IsConnected-> {as:network}
 RETURN $elements
```

If you have multiple paths connected to the same node, you can use comma separated patterns, joined using aliases, eg.

```
MATCH
 {as:user} -Performs-> {as:process} -Uses->
 {class:Application, as:app, where:(applicationName = ?)} -RunsOn-> 
 {class:Server, as:server, where:(osType = ?)} -IsConnected-> {as:network},
 {as:server} -IsMountedOn-> {as:storage}
RETURN $elements
```

If one or more of the (terminal) connections is missing, you can define it as optional, eg. if the storage can be missing:

```
MATCH
 {as:user} -Performs-> {as:process} -Uses->
 {class:Application, as:app, where:(applicationName = ?)} -RunsOn-> 
 {class:Server, as:server, where:(osType = ?)} -IsConnected-> {as:network},
 {as:server} -IsMountedOn-> {as:storage, optional:true}
RETURN $elements
```

This works only on terminal nodes, ie. nodes that have only one connection.

Full reference here: http://orientdb.com/docs/2.2.x/SQL-Match.html

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.Somewhere I am looking for the same result down the line.One small doubt if we have more then one dependent Vertex then how we will put it into the same query like Server IsMountedOn Storage and Server IsConnectedTo Network.

Comment: Added an example to the original answer

Comment: But I am not able to understand How to define another 3 relationship for the same Server like if i m doing {as:Server}-IsMountedOn->{as:Storage}-IsConnectedTo->{as:Network} but it is not working because this network is directly related to Server.

Comment: Ohh my bad...got it ...Thanks...!!

Comment: It is not working in all the cases...We have two Server records but if one Server is not attached with the Network then it is not returning any result.

Is it possible in MATCH condition to check whether any relationship is exist or not between the vertex,Still it will return result.

Comment: Updated the original post with an answer ;-)

Comment: Thanks got it Luigi and optional tag will work only right side .But I am facing some issues like relationship Vertex itself is not present for some conditions.

Like one Server is VirtualizedOn some Cloud and this Cloud is HostedOn some Datacenter.In this case if I am checking like {as:Server}-VirtualizedOn->{optional:true,as:Cloud}, its working fine because cloud may not be there but if i m checking {as:Cloud}-HostedOn->{optional:true,as:Datacenter}, this case is not working because Cloud is not there and i need to check this case also.

Comment: In this case you have to use a sub-query, eg. ```SELECT *, cloud.out("HostedOn") as dc FROM (MATCH ...) UNWIND dc```

Comment: Some exception Luigi.....I think some issues with writing the query..Can u plz check it would be really great help.

Comment: Select User.*,Process.*,Application.*,SubSystem.*,Server.*,Storage.*,Network.*,CloudName.*,Datacenter.*,Location.*,CloudName.out("IsHostedOn") as cd from(MATCH {as:User}-Performs->{as:Process}-Uses->{class:Application,as:Application,where:(name='BookMyflowers')}-DependsOn->{as:SubSystem}-RunsOn->{class:Server,as:Server,where:(name='10.236.220.154-LinuxOS')}-IsMountedOn->{as:Storage},{as:Server}-IsConnectedTo->{optional:true,as:Network},{as:Server}-IsVirtualizedOn->{optional:true,as:CloudName},as:CloudName}.out('IsHostedOn'){optional:true,as:Datacenter} RETURN User,Process) UNWIND cd

Comment: Try this: Select User.*,Process.*,Application.*,SubSystem.*,Server.*,Storage.‌*,Network.*,CloudNam‌​e.*,Datacenter.*,Loc‌​ation.*,
CloudName.ou‌t("IsHostedOn") as cd from (
MATCH {as:User}-Performs->{as:Process}-Uses->{class:Application,as‌​:Application,where:(‌​name='BookMyflowers'‌​)}
-DependsOn->{as:Su‌bSystem}-RunsOn->{cl‌​ass:Server,as:Server‌​,where:(name='10.236‌​.220.154-LinuxOS')}-‌IsMountedOn->
{as:Sto‌rage},{as:Server}-Is‌​ConnectedTo->{option‌​al:true,as:Network},‌​
{as:Server}-IsVirtua‌​lizedOn->{optional:t‌​rue,as:CloudName},as‌​:CloudName}
 RETURN User,Process) UNWIND cd

Comment: Luigi your query has a syntax error even after resolving,it is not working.

Comment: Sorry, wrong cut/paste: Select User.*,Process.*,Application.*,SubSystem.*,Server.*,Storage.*,Network.*,CloudName.*,Datacenter.*,Location.*, CloudName.out("IsHostedOn") as cd 
from ( 
  MATCH {as:User} -Performs-> {as:Process} -Uses-> {class:Application,as:Application,where:(name='BookMyflowers')} -DependsOn-> {as:SubSystem} -RunsOn-> {class:Server,as:Server,where:(name='10.236.220.154-LinuxOS')} -IsMountedOn-> {as:Storage}, {as:Server} -IsConnectedTo-> {optional:true, as:Network},  {as:Server}-IsVirtualizedOn->{optional:true, as:CloudName} RETURN User,Process
) UNWIND cd

Comment: Hey till here its working for me also without UNWIND because we are using optional:true for CloudName but just after this next relationship is not working {as:CloudName}-IsHostedOn->{optional:true,as:Datacenter} even after UNWIND. Because we already used optional:true for CloudName.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't get the point: you cannot have a non-terminal optional node, this is why I removed Datacenter from the MATCH and added an outer SELECT/UNWIND

Comment: Luigi, It is like I want to check both condition :
1st : {as:Server}-IsVirtualizedOn->{optional:true,as:CloudName} It is working fine because we have checked like optional:true.So,whether CloudName is there or not,it will work.
2nd : {as:CloudName}-IsHostedOn->{optional:true,as:Datacenter}  I want to check here whether CloudName is exist or not query MATCH will give some result but in this case CloudName is not there so query MATCH result is some exception or error.

I have read out like we can't put optional:true in the left side.

Comment: Luigi, I need details for both the Datacenter and Location but using below query i m only able to get the details of Datacenter. Can u plz help me out for the same.

Comment: Select User.*,CloudName.out("IsHostedOn") as dc,Datacenter.out("IsLocatedIn") as loc from ( MATCH {as:User} -Performs-> {as:Process} -Uses-> {class:Application,as:Application,where:(name='BookMyflowers')} -DependsOn-> {as:SubSystem} -RunsOn-> {class:Server,as:Server,where:(name='10.236.220.161-Windows')} -IsMountedOn-> {as:Storage}, {as:Server} -IsConnectedTo-> {optional:true, as:Network}, {as:Server}-IsVirtualizedOn->{optional:true, as:CloudName},{class:Datacenter,as:Datacenter}-IsLocatedIn->{class:Location,optional:true,as:Location} RETURN User,CloudName,dc,loc) UNWIND dc,loc